# how to search for the first word of a sentence in word

Tags: regex, ms-word, replace

I have the following script that will find a period followed by 2 or more spaces, but what I'm looking for is to be able to find the first word of a sentence and if it's "Medical" then it will change it.  I was hoping to capitalize off of this script but I can already tell if it's the first word of a paragraph it'll be missed, and I'm not sure how to have it search properly for ". Medical"

```
     With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Highlight = False
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Highlight = True
    .Text = (\.)( {2,9})
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

I ended up finding another post at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096523/make-the-first-letter-bold-on-each-sentence-in-ms-word-document) and came up with this:

```
         Dim i As Integer
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To doc.Sentences.Count
    If doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Medical " Then
        doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Medical (needs removal) "
    End If
    If doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Dental " Then
        doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Dental (needs removal) "
    End If
    If doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Life " Then
        doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Life (needs removal) "
    End If
    If doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Vision " Then
        doc.Sentences(i).Words(1) = "Vision (needs removal) "
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet from that code block:

```
    .Text = (\. )( )+Medical
    .Replacement.Text = \1XX
```

XX = Whatever you want to change the word Medical to.

`(\. )` matches the end of a sentence.

`( )+` matches extraneous spaces.

This should both fix your multiple spaces issue and change Medical to whatever you want.

*I have not tested this. Please use discretion.*

Comment: Could you look at this post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711764/vba-word-find-hyperlinks-if-not-arial-10pt-blue)